# Convert coreplot chart point into superview's coordinate space

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-plot, cgpoint

We're using `CorePlot` to draw a chart. In the yAxis we draw the temperature.

Given a temperature value, we want to find the `y coordinate` that corresponds to that temperature in the UIViewController's coordinate space.

Our view hierarchy is organized the following way:

```
_ UIViewController's main view (self.view)
 \_ UIScrollView
   \_ ChartView
```

Reading the docs, we've found [-[CTPAxis viewPointForCoordinateDecimalNumber:]](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_axis.html#af25bf15f120918facdcd1a73ff0f963c) that should do exactly what we want.

Now, since that method would return the Y position in the ChartView's coordinate system, we use [-[UIView convertPoint:toView:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:) to do the translation from the ChartView to the UIScrollView and then to the UIViewController's main view:

```
//self is the UIViewController
CGPoint *originalPoint = [self.temperatureAxis viewPointForCoordinateDecimalNumber:temperature];
CGPoint *scrollViewConvertedPoint = [self.chartView convertPoint:originalPoint toView:self.scrollView];
CGPoint *finalPoint = [self.scrollView convertPoint:scrollViewConvertedPoint toView:self.view];
```

Using this method, we're obtaining incorrect values as seen in the next picture.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `originalPoint` is in the coordinate space of the plot area. Convert it to the graph's coordinate space before doing the view conversions.

```
CGPoint graphPoint = [graph convertPoint:originalPoint 
                               fromLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, `graphPoint` results in the same as `originalPoint` after doing the conversation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to using the plot space methods for converting to and from drawing coordinates. Those do use the plot area. Replace the `plotArea` with `self.temperatureAxis` in my answer to convert the point returned from the axis method.